# onHover for View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have tried to implement a `onHoverListener` on a button in android programming, however, I found that `onHover` is not available in the library.

But I have seen a sample code in the developer section, may I know how to get this `onHover` works on button? Or does it only support some `View`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code for onHoverListener. You can try this. http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Hover.html

Comment: yup i have seen the sample code, but when i'm trying to use onHover on button, it does not support this method?

Comment: Yes button supports onHover event. But you need to know that onHover method is Supported from API level 14 , Android 4.0.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html